# tibco parse only few field from text to xml

Tags: xml, parsing, tibco, tibco-designer

im using tibco and need to recover 3 xml field from an input who is in text format. Normally i will parse the whole message in xml and extract the 3 field i need but the xml format as been lost.

Is there a way to recover the 3 field without recreate the xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution myself:

You can simply configure the output of the parse xml to an any object element. And write the path the same way you have an xml scheme

exemple :

[image]

edit : 
don't forget to configure the validation in 'lax' :

[image]